# Redefinition of Class: Maximilian Sound Library with JUCE

Tags: c++, audio, juce

I have a problem with using the Maximilian Sound Library with the JUCE Audio framework. I tried to include the library by putting the path of the library into the "header search path"-segment of the Xcode debug exporter as following: [image]
Then I added the library folder to my source folder:
[image]
When I start xCode and try to build the project, I get multiple errors which say "Redefinition of *some_classname*"

Example:
[image]
[image]

I am a complete beginner to c++ and audio programming in general (not programming in general though). I wanted to look into it by following a youtube tutorial. I followed every step but ended up getting these errors. It would be nice if someone could help me. Thank you very much.

Snerps

Link to the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gsd7ESq827c&t=136s

Answer (score 0):

The errors disappear after deleting the files maxSynths.cpp and maxSynths.h from the libs folder of the library. I got this solution from another tutorial from the same channel.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEDr-gJxc_I